# Cygwin binutils error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: gcc, cygwin, mingw

I was trying to compile binutils and I got this error saying :
C compiler cannot create executables

I need help. I am totally frustrated. If you want to know why I am doing this then my answer is don't ask.

Actually I am trying to build a GCC cross complier with Cygwin.

Here is the log :

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../binutils-2.27/configure --target=i686-elf --prefix=/home/Arunav Das/opt/cross --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = DESKTOP-JCP0DAS
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 2.6.1(0.305/5/3)
uname -s = CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW
uname -v = 2016-12-16 11:50

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = i686
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/Arunav Das/opt/cross/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Windows
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/2.0/bin/x86
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/2.0/bin/x64
PATH: /cygdrive/d/DEFPC/3.0.0/bin/i386-Win32
PATH: /cygdrive/d/Program Files/CMake/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/d/DE/FPC/3.0.0/bin/i386-Win32
PATH: /cygdrive/d/Program Files/IDM Computer Solutions/UEStudio
PATH: /cygdrive/c/TDM-GCC-32-GTK/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/d/DE/TDM-GCC-32-GTK/TDM-GCC-32/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/d/Program Files/Ruby192/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32
PATH: /cygdrive/d/Program Files/FreeArc/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/u/Program Files/Mercurial


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2297: checking build system type
configure:2311: result: i686-pc-cygwin
configure:2358: checking host system type
configure:2371: result: i686-pc-cygwin
configure:2391: checking target system type
configure:2404: result: i686-pc-elf
configure:2458: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2526: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2537: checking whether ln works
configure:2559: result: yes
configure:2563: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2567: result: yes
configure:2574: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2638: result: /usr/bin/sed
configure:2647: checking for gawk
configure:2663: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2674: result: gawk
configure:3995: checking to see if cat works as expected
configure:4000: result: yes
configure:4121: checking for gcc
configure:4137: found /cygdrive/d/DE/FPC/3.0.0/bin/i386-Win32/gcc
configure:4148: result: gcc
configure:4377: checking for C compiler version
configure:4386: gcc --version >&5
2.95
configure:4397: $? = 0
configure:4386: gcc -v >&5
Using builtin specs.
gcc version 2.95 19990728 (release)
configure:4397: $? = 0
configure:4386: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:4397: $? = 1
configure:4386: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc.exe: unrecognized option `-qversion'
gcc.exe: No input files
configure:4397: $? = 1
configure:4417: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4439: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc.exe: installation problem, cannot exec `cc1': No such file or directory
configure:4443: $? = 1
configure:4480: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4486: error: in `/home/Arunav Das/src/build-binutils':
configure:4490: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i686-pc-cygwin
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AR_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_value=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=i686-elf
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_value=
ac_cv_host=i686-pc-cygwin
ac_cv_path_SED=/usr/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_target=i686-pc-elf
acx_cv_prog_LN=ln

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
AR_FOR_BUILD='$(AR)'
AR_FOR_TARGET=''
AS=''
AS_FOR_BUILD='$(AS)'
AS_FOR_TARGET=''
AWK='gawk'
BISON=''
BUILD_CONFIG=''
CC='gcc'
CC_FOR_BUILD='$(CC)'
CC_FOR_TARGET=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET=''
CONFIGURE_GDB_TK=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
CXX_FOR_BUILD='$(CXX)'
CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD='$(DLLTOOL)'
DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPECT=''
EXTRA_CONFIGARGS_LIBJAVA='--disable-static'
FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
FLEX=''
GCC_FOR_TARGET=''
GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
GCJ_FOR_BUILD='$(GCJ)'
GCJ_FOR_TARGET=''
GDB_TK=''
GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD='$(GFORTRAN)'
GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET=''
GNATBIND=''
GNATMAKE=''
GOC_FOR_BUILD='$(GOC)'
GOC_FOR_TARGET=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
LD_FOR_BUILD='$(LD)'
LD_FOR_TARGET=''
LEX=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO=''
LIPO_FOR_TARGET=''
LN='ln'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
M4=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO=''
NM=''
NM_FOR_BUILD='$(NM)'
NM_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
RANLIB_FOR_BUILD='$(RANLIB)'
RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=''
RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
READELF=''
READELF_FOR_TARGET=''
RPATH_ENVVAR=''
RUNTEST=''
SED='/usr/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
STRIP_FOR_TARGET=''
SYSROOT_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS='../binutils-2.27/configure --target=i686-elf --prefix='\''/home/Arunav Das/opt/cross'\'' --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror'
WINDMC=''
WINDMC_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDMC)'
WINDMC_FOR_TARGET=''
WINDRES=''
WINDRES_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDRES)'
WINDRES_FOR_TARGET=''
YACC=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-pc-cygwin'
build_alias=''
build_configargs=''
build_configdirs='build-libiberty build-libcpp build-texinfo build-flex build-bison build-m4 build-fixincludes'
build_cpu='i686'
build_libsubdir='build-i686-pc-cygwin'
build_noncanonical='i686-pc-cygwin'
build_os='cygwin'
build_subdir='build-i686-pc-cygwin'
build_tooldir=''
build_vendor='pc'
compare_exclusions=''
configdirs='intl libiberty opcodes bfd readline tcl tk itcl libgui zlib libbacktrace libcpp libdecnumber gmp mpfr mpc isl libelf libiconv texinfo flex bison binutils gas ld fixincludes gcc cgen sid sim gdb gprof etc expect dejagnu m4 utils guile fastjar gnattools libcc1 gotools libtermcap'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
do_compare=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags=''
extra_host_zlib_configure_flags=''
extra_isl_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_liboffloadmic_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_flags=''
extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags=''
extra_mpfr_configure_flags=''
gmpinc=''
gmplibs=''
host='i686-pc-cygwin'
host_alias=''
host_configargs=''
host_cpu='i686'
host_noncanonical='i686-pc-cygwin'
host_os='cygwin'
host_shared=''
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
islinc=''
isllibs=''
islver=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
poststage1_ldflags=''
poststage1_libs=''
prefix='/home/Arunav Das/opt/cross'
program_transform_name='s&^&i686-elf-&'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
stage1_cflags=''
stage1_checking=''
stage1_languages=''
stage1_ldflags=''
stage1_libs=''
stage2_werror_flag=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='i686-pc-elf'
target_alias='i686-elf'
target_configargs=''
target_configdirs='target-libgcc target-libbacktrace target-libgloss target-newlib target-libgomp target-libcilkrts target-liboffloadmic target-libatomic target-libitm target-libstdc++-v3 target-libsanitizer target-libvtv target-libmpx target-libssp target-libquadmath target-libgfortran target-boehm-gc target-libffi target-zlib target-libjava target-libobjc target-libada target-libgo target-rda'
target_cpu='i686'
target_noncanonical='i686-elf'
target_os='elf'
target_subdir='i686-elf'
target_vendor='pc'
tooldir=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

alphaieee_frag=''
host_makefile_frag='config/mh-cygwin'
ospace_frag=''
serialization_dependencies=''
target_makefile_frag=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is the important one to look at:

```
configure:4439: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc.exe: installation problem, cannot exec `cc1': No such file or directory
```

Do you have a working compiler installed?  Can you compile a simple "hello, world" program?  Try that first.